# How can I make an NPN transistor in The Powder Toy?

Tags: the-powder-toy

I'm trying to make a transistor in TPT.

In other words, it should logically behave like this:
E≡B∧C, E≡¬(B⊃C)

Although, as it's a transistor, it may be written better as
E≡(C⊅B)∧(B⊅C)

I tried to use this but it didn't work:

[image]

How I can properly build an NPN transistor?